# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "float" в "UnityEngine.vector3"

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу довольно простую игру, типа fps шутер. Столкнулся с проблемой, а именно:

```
    Vector3 mov_horizontal = transform.right = xMov;
    Vector3 mov_vertical = transform.forward = zMov;
```

Компилятор ругается на xMov && zMov, пишет:

> Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "float" в "UnityEngine.vector3"

Весь код:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlaerModer))]
    public class PlaerControiler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private float speed = 5f;

        private PlaerModer motor;

        private void Start()
        {
            motor = GetComponent<PlaerModer>();
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            float xMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float zMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            //Ошибка здесь
            Vector3 mov_horizontal = transform.right = xMov;
            Vector3 mov_vertical = transform.forward = zMov;

            Vector3 velocity = (mov_horizontal + mov_vertical).normalized * speed;

            motor.Move(velocity);
        }
    }
```

Сейчас ошибка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Vector3 right = new Vector3(xMov, transform.right.y, transform.right.z);
    transform.right = right;
    Vector3 forward = new Vector3(transform.forward.x, transform.forward.y, zMov);
    transform.forward = forward;

    Vector3 velocity = (new Vector3(xMov, 0, zMov)).normalized * speed;
```

Comment: Все равно ругается на строчку transform.right = xMov;

Comment: @АйзекАзимов в ответе то строчка не так выглядит

Comment: @tym32167 Это я только что исправил.

Comment: а, тогда вопросов нет

Comment: @Igor Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение "tramsgform.right" т.к. оно не является переменной